# Group-specific calculation on Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm wondering what is the most elegant/pythonic way of subtracting the brand-specific mean price from the price in the following DataFrame.

Put differently, I want to create a second column equal to the original price minus 1200 for Apple products, and equal to the original price minus 700 for Lenovo products.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO('''product,brand,price
macbook,Apple,1000
macbook air,Apple,1200
macbook pro,Apple,1400
thinkbook,Lenovo,600
thinkpad,Lenovo,800
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract the grouped by mean from the price to create a new column called `Price_Diff_Mean`. Use `.transform('mean')` to create a series of values of same length to the column `price` and subtract those values from `price`:

```
df['Price_Diff_Mean'] = df['price'] - df.groupby('brand')['price'].transform('mean')
df
Out[6]: 
       product   brand  price  Price_Diff_Mean
0      macbook   Apple   1000             -200
1  macbook air   Apple   1200                0
2  macbook pro   Apple   1400              200
3    thinkbook  Lenovo    600             -100
4     thinkpad  Lenovo    800              100
```

Alternatively, you can add a column in with `.assign` , which will give you the same result:

```
df = df.assign(Price_Diff_Mean = df['price'] - df.groupby('brand')['price'].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of the transform method. Thanks.

Comment: @MaximilianoSantiago no problem. `transform` is an absolutely key method if you are ever trying to get the data into a column. Otherwise, if you don't use it, you will just get `NaN` values as a result.

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly more elegant way, in my opinion:

```
df['newcolumn'] = df.groupby('brand').transform(lambda x: x - x.mean())
```